# Selecting a table of data VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am very new to VBA/coding and so I'm in need of some help and so will likely be posting on here quite a bit within the next few weeks. I have been teaching myself as much as I can over the last week or so and I have decided to start a project.

I need to select and copy a table of data but the problem is the table of data changes size every single day so I cannot set a specific range. The code I am using is this but it isn't selecting the whole table.

```
Workbooks.open "filepath\filename.xls"
Workbooks ("filename.xls").Activate
Range ("b8").Select
Range (Selection, Selection.end(xlDown)).Select
Range (Selection, Selection.end(xlToRight)).Select
```

The attached picture is the table and the first cell with data in is b8(Target SLA & Category) and I want it to copy down to the bottom right of the image. as i have stated the table changes size each day so I can't have a set range. [Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoYGY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can select the table instead of a range of cells (change "Table1" to whatever your table is named).

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the overall design of your table does not change (i.e. the first observation is always in cell `B8`) you can use

```
Sub SelectData()

    Dim rngData As Range

    Set rngData = Worksheets("Table1").UsedRange
    rngData.Offset(7, 1).Resize(rngData.Rows.Count - 7, rngData.Columns.Count - 1).Select

End Sub
```

In case there can be changes, the following should be quite robust:

```
Sub SelectData()

    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intColumn As Integer

        intRow = Range("Table1!FirstDataPoint").Row
        intColumn = Range("Table1!FirstDataPoint").Column

        Set rngData = Worksheets("Table1").UsedRange
        rngData.Offset(intRow - 1, intColumn - 1).Resize(rngData.Rows.Count - intRow + 1, rngData.Columns.Count - intColumn + 1).Select

End Sub
```

In order to apply this you have to name the upper left data point, in your case cell `B8` (I used the name "FirstDataPoint"). When you insert rows or columns to the left or above of this cell the code should still work.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this with many different alterations and all I get back is run time error 1004, application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: That's strange. I tested it and it worked perfectly for me. In which line does the error occur?

Comment: You can step through the code line by line by pressing F8. The error most likely occurs because you have used a different name either for the worksheet or for the first cell containing data (here B8).